# vtiger 6.4 vtwsclib doInvoke() custom webservice not working

Tags: php, web-services, vtigercrm

I'm trying to call a custom webservice from an external php file but it's not working. In order to create the custom webservice I followed this post ([How to Create custom operation for Webservice VtigerCRM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38931706/how-to-create-custom-operation-for-webservice-vtigercrm)), so I first ran a query to add the new webservice in vtiger_ws_operation table:

```
INSERT INTO `vtiger_ws_operation` ( `name`, `handler_path`, `handler_method`, `type`, `prelogin`) VALUES ('my_webservice_method', 'include/Webservices/WbsWebserviceMethod.php', 'vtws_my_webservice_method’, 'GET', 0);
```

then I added a new row in vtiger_ws_operation_parameters with the only parameter I need for this webservice:

```
INSERT INTO `vtiger_ws_operation_parameters` (`operationid`, `name`, `type`, `sequence`) VALUES (35, 'key', 'String', 1);
```

finally, I added my php file 'include/Webservices/WbsWebserviceMethod.php':

```
<?php
function vtws_my_webservice_method($key) {
    global $log,$adb;
    return "ok";
}
?>
```

But when I try and call this webservice from my external file, it returns false:

```
$results = $client->doInvoke(
    'vtws_my_webservice_method',
    array('key' => $date),
    'GET'
);
var_dump($results);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The method name exposed to the outside world is the name column - **my_webservice_method** in your case. So your code should be something like -

```
$results = $client->doInvoke(
    'my_webservice_method',
    array('key' => $date),
    'GET'
);
var_dump($results);
```

Please let me know if this works.